# Admobs interstitial ad won't show iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob

So, I had the interstitial ads working fine by following the code on the Admob website and then recently I updated my pods and with it the GoogleAdMob SDK.

Now when my interstitial Ad should present, nothing happens and in the console I have this error:

<GoogleThe provided view controller is not being presented.

[ProcessSuspension] 0x110adfbd0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()

Here is my code:

```
extension FirstViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
    
    func showInterstitialAd() {
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
          } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
          }
    }
    
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    
}
```

In viewDidLoad I call:

```
func setUpInterstitial() {
        
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
    }
```

and in ViewWillAppear

```
if InterstitialAd.counter >= 3 { self.showInterstitialAd(); InterstitialAd.counter = 0}
```

The intended logic is every 3 times a user views a page, namely FirstViewController, an interstitial ad shows.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code like below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if InterstitialAd.counter >= 3 {
        self.showInterstitialAd(); 
        InterstitialAd.counter = 0
    }
}
```

Remove your code from viewWillAppear.

Comment: You sir are a legend. I would have never thought of this solution! Cheers